# Trying to make mongodb start on startup Debian 9

Tags: startup, services, debian, mongodb

So when I type:
`sudo update-rc.d mongod defaults`

I get:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "he_IL.UTF-8",
    LC_PAPER = "he_IL.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "he_IL.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "he_IL.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "he_IL.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "he_IL.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "he_IL.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "he_IL.UTF-8",
    LC_TIME = "he_IL.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_US.UTF-8").
update-rc.d: error: unable to read /etc/init.d/mongod
```

When I type:`sudo update-rc.d mongod enable`

I get:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "he_IL.UTF-8",
    LC_PAPER = "he_IL.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "he_IL.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "he_IL.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "he_IL.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "he_IL.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "he_IL.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "he_IL.UTF-8",
    LC_TIME = "he_IL.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_US.UTF-8").
update-rc.d: error: cannot find a LSB script for mongod
```

I also found out that: `sudo ls -al /etc/init.d/ | grep mongod` returns nothing. 
Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Lets check its status first `systemctl status mongodb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I type: `sudo update-rc.d mongod defaults`

Do not do that.  `update-rc.d` is not a tool for you to run directly.  It is for maintainer scripts.  On a systemd operating system like yours, use `systemctl enable` and `systemctl disable`.

> When I type: `sudo update-rc.d mongod enable`

The service is not named `mongod` on Debian in any case.  `mongod` is the service name used in the service definitions provided by the MongoDB developers. 
 But Debian supplies its own service definitions, and on Debian the service is named `mongodb`.

> `sudo ls -al /etc/init.d/ | grep mongod` returns nothing

This is a symptom of your not having installed the `mongodb-server` package in the first place.

The perl messages about your locale are a red herring, and are almost certainly a result of [Debian bug #868695](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=868695).  A [local fix](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/fix-terminology.html) is to ensure that your `LANGUAGE` and `LC_ALL` variables are also set by your shell's login script; but this isn't anything to do with your service units and missing files.